# How to recognize groups in a column and outer border them?

Tags: python, pandas

My input is this simple dataframe :

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'class': ['class_a', 'class_a', 'class_a', 'class_b', 'class_c', 'class_c'],
 'name': ['name_1', 'name_2', 'name_3', 'name_1', 'name_1', 'name_2'],
 'id': [5, 7, 1, 2, 3, 8]})
print(df)

     class    name  id
0  class_a  name_1   5
1  class_a  name_2   7
2  class_a  name_3   1
3  class_b  name_1   2
4  class_c  name_1   3
5  class_c  name_2   8
```

I want to draw a blue solid border (a blue rectangle) around each group in the column `class`.

I found a solution in stackoverflow [Pandas Style: Draw borders over whole row including the multiindex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65939324/pandas-style-draw-borders-over-whole-row-including-the-multiindex)

```
s = df.style
for idx, group_df in df.groupby('class'):
    s = s.set_table_styles({group_df.index[0]: [{'selector': '', 'props': 'border-top: 3px solid blue;'}]}, 
                       overwrite=False, axis=1)
```

But there is two problems :

1. the outer border are missing
2. the styles are lost when I save it to excel

[image]

Is there a change guys we could fix at least "point 1" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To draw a blue rectangle around each group in the class column, you will need to set the top, bottom, left, and right borders for the grouped rows. This requires setting the borders for the first and last rows of each group, and also for the entire group. This can be achieved like below

```
import pandas as pd

# Sample data
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'class': ['class_a', 'class_a', 'class_a', 'class_b', 'class_c', 'class_c'],
    'name': ['name_1', 'name_2', 'name_3', 'name_1', 'name_1', 'name_2'],
    'id': [5, 7, 1, 2, 3, 8]
})

def style_border_around_class_groups(df):
    # Get the start and end indices of each group
    start_indices = df.groupby('class').head(1).index
    end_indices = df.groupby('class').tail(1).index

    # Define a dictionary to store styles for each cell
    styles_dict = {}

    # For each row in the dataframe
    for i, row in df.iterrows():
        # Default styles
        top_border = ""
        bottom_border = ""
        left_border = ""
        right_border = ""

        # If the row index is a start index, add top border
        if i in start_indices:
            top_border = "3px solid blue"
        # If the row index is an end index, add bottom border
        if i in end_indices:
            bottom_border = "3px solid blue"

        # Apply horizontal borders to all columns
        for col in df.columns:
            styles_dict[(i, col)] = f"border-top: {top_border}; border-bottom: {bottom_border};"

        # Apply left border only to the first column
        styles_dict[(i, df.columns[0])] += "border-left: 3px solid blue;"

        # Apply right border only to the last column
        styles_dict[(i, df.columns[-1])] += "border-right: 3px solid blue;"

    # Apply the styles
    s = df.style.apply(lambda x: [styles_dict.get((x.name, col), "") for col in df.columns], axis=1)
    return s

# Apply the styling function
styled_df = style_border_around_class_groups(df)
styled_df
```

which results in

[image: Output image]

Comment: You're great. There is only one problem. The two vertical bars between class and name and between name and id should be removed. Can you fix that, please ?

Comment: @VERBOSE : Answer edited. I hope the output now works for you. Give it a try and see if it works for you.